# SPRING BOOT infinite recursion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have two entitys, Student and Subject. This two class have a many to many relationship. The thing is when i try to link a Subject with Student, not work give me a error. Looks like infinite recursion issue.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Exam> exams;

    public boolean addSubject(Subject subject){
        return subjects.add(subject);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Subjects_Students",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Student> students;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="subject")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Exam> exams;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Teacher teacher;

    public boolean addStudent(Student student) {
        return students.add(student);
    }
}
```

the methodo i use int the service is:

```
@PostMapping("/{studentId}/subject/{subjectId}")
public ResponseEntity<Student> addSubject(@PathVariable Long studentId, @PathVariable Long subjectId ){
    return studentService.addSubject(studentId,subjectId);
}
```

And the error:

Hibernate: select subjects0_.student_id as student_2_4_0_, subjects0_.subject_id as subject_1_4_0_, subject1_.id as id1_3_1_, subject1_.name as name2_3_1_, subject1_.teacher_id as teacher_3_3_1_, teacher2_.id as id1_5_2_, teacher2_.name as name2_5_2_ from subjects_students subjects0_ inner join subject subject1_ on subjects0_.subject_id=subject1_.id left outer join teacher teacher2_ on subject1_.teacher_id=teacher2_.id where subjects0_.student_id=?

Please help me, this is driving creazy

Comment: Try to add default value for `students` and `subjects`.
`... = new HashSet<>();`. Also, avoid [using `@Data` on your entities](https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/)

Comment: What you posted isn't an error, it is just a query string- post the full error message and part of the stack as it will probably help you. Turn off Lombok and generate the accessors yourself and it should work. As https://stackoverflow.com/a/74905342/496099 hinted at, Lombok is likely using your relationships within the equals and hashcode methods (Lombok shouldn't be used without knowing what it generates!), and Set requires using them to populate - which causes it to traverse your object model recursively. You might also be able to switch to using List instead of set, but more could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try exclude `hash code` method auto generated by Lombok `@Data` annotation:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "subjects" })
public class Student {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Subject> subjects;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "students" })
public class Subject {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Subjects_Students",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Student> students;
}
```

Comment: It ´s not work :(

Comment: Because it isn't enough. You have multiple relationships in these entities, forcing any remaining to all be included in the equals and hashcode methods. Any not excluded will be accessed when ever equals/hashcode are called. As you have Set used within all entities, you should know that it requires calling hashcode to determine identity. So it is called on every entity within these collections as they are being built. And it'll be wrong as they are not immutable and the entities themselves might not be fully built. Don't have Lombok generate equals and hash at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({<entity_class_name>})` to skip the recursive call.

On student class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"Subject"})
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Exam> exams;

    public boolean addSubject(Subject subject){
        return subjects.add(subject);
    }
}
```

and on subject class

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"Student"})
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Subjects_Students",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Student> students;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="subject")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Exam> exams;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Teacher teacher;

    public boolean addStudent(Student student) {
        return students.add(student);
    }
}
```